# Form for tags not accepting angular js attributes

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-3

I have form tag helpers such as

```
form_for(:session, url: sessions_path, name: "signin_form", "ng-controller": 
"signinctrl") do |f| %>
```

Whenever I go the page however I get an error from rails saying

```
unexpected tASSOC
```

Why is Rails not accepting the `ng-controller` attribute? My controller is defined in a different file and my ng-app is defined in the html tag.

Comment: it seems you forgot to close quotes for signing form, it should be `"signin_form", ng-controller: "signinctrl"`

Comment: also because of the dash change ng-controller to "ng-controller":"signinctrl"

Comment: My apologizes, I did not copy the code correctly. There should be a double parentheses after signin_form. I'll fix that now.

Comment: Hmm... now I'm getting the error `expecting tASSOC` when I add the parentheses around `ng-controller`.

Comment: I haven't used rails in a while, perhaps if you pass the hash key as a symbol `:"ng-controller"=> "..."`

Comment: Still no result. Thanks for the try though.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here: `"ng-controller": "signinctrl"`

The Ruby 1.9 hash syntax only supports symbols (without colons), such as `ng-controller: "signinctrl"` (which would be the same as `:ng-controller => "signinctrl"`.

To fix it, you'll just have to use the 1.8-style hash syntax. You can mix and match that into the hash without changing the rest of the properties:

```
form_for(:session, url: sessions_path, name: "signin_form", "ng-controller" => "signinctrl") do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try with "data-ng-controller" ?

Comment: No more ideas. Sorry for you :s